# Constexpr member function in class template

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constexpr

The following code fails to compile:

```
// template<class>
struct S {
    int g() const {
        return 0;
    }

    constexpr int f() const {
        return g();
    }
};

int main()
{
    S /*<int>*/ s;
    auto z = s.f();
}
```

GCC, for example, complains: *error: call to non-constexpr function ‘int S::g() const’*. This is perfectly reasonable. But if I turn *S* into a template, the code compiles (checked with MSVC 15.3, GCC 7.1.0, clang 4.0.1).

Why? Does *constexpr* has any special meaning in class templates?

As far as I understand it, this code is incorrect, but the standard does not require that compilers produce an error (why?).

Comment: On one hand, interesting behavior. On the other, why call a non constexpr function from a constexpr function ever?

Comment: @AndyG This is just a minimal example. In my case `S` was a template class that was derived from different base classes depending on a template parameter. `g()`'s were in bases classes. Then I made `f()` `constexpr` and made `g()` `constexpr` only in _some_ bases classes (where `constexpr`ness made sense). I was perplexed to see no compiler error when `S` was derived from a base class with non-`constexpr` `g()`. Hence, the question.

Comment: It had better be, because we want to be able to have a template class with methods that are maybe constexpr depending on its template parameters, and maybe not.  I don't know where in the standard this is permitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per [dcl.constexpr]

> The definition of a constexpr function shall satisfy the following constraints:
>   ...
> every constructor call and implicit conversion used in initializing the return value (6.6.3, 8.5) shall be
>   one of those allowed in a constant expression

A call to `g()` is not allowed in a constant expression. Per [expr.const]:

> A *conditional-expression* is a *core constant expression* unless it involves one of the following as a potentially
>   evaluated subexpression...: 
>   — an invocation of a function other than [...] a `constexpr` function

It looks like some compilers may allow you to do what you're doing because `z` isn't declared `constexpr` so the value doesn't need to be known at compile-time. If you change your code to

```
constexpr auto z = s.f();
```

you'll note that all those compilers will proceed to barf, template or not.

Comment: Zero can even be replaced with something like `getchar()`.

Comment: From the [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr): _A `constexpr` function must satisfy the following requirements: ... there exists at least one set of argument values such that an invocation of the function could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression (for constructors, use in a constant initializer is sufficient) (since C++14). No diagnostic is required for a violation of this bullet._ The question is then, why no diagnostic is required?

Comment: @Evgeny: Good catch on the no diagnostic required aspect. The usual explanation is that enforcing something would either take way too much time or is impossible to do for all inputs.

Comment: @AngyG Producing no error makes `constexpr` conditional, so to speak, and it seems to be quite useful. Under some appropriate wording that could've been probably allowed by the standard.