# Is this a bug? Constexpr constructor silently becomes non-constexpr

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

Look at this code:

```
struct NonConstexpr {
    NonConstexpr() { }
};

template <typename T>
struct Bar {
    NonConstexpr nonConstexpr;

    constexpr Bar() { }
};

struct Foo {
    Bar<void> bar;

    constexpr Foo() { }
};
```

`Foo` has a member, `Foo::bar::nonConstexpr`, which has a non-constexpr constructor. So, my expectation is that this should not compile. But it compiles with gcc, clang and msvc. Is this a compiler bug, or some rule allows this code to compile?

If I add a `NonConstexpr` member into `Foo` directly, the code doesn't compile anymore.

(I got this problem, because I've expected static initialization for a global `Foo` object, but it got dynamically initialized, and it caused a problem, because of "static initialization order fiasco")

Comment: GCC does not compile this code if `Bar` is not a template. Probably, a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46119548/constexpr-member-function-in-class-template

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is this a compiler bug, or some rule allows this code to compile?

The rule that allows this to compile is:

> **10.1.5 The constexpr speciﬁer [dcl.constexpr]**
>   ...
>   6. If the instantiated template specialization of a `constexpr` function template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy the requirements for a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor, that specialization is still a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor, even though a call to such a function cannot appear in a constant expression. If no specialization of the template would satisfy the requirements for a `constexpr` function or `constexpr` constructor when considered as a non-template function or constructor, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

The above quote is taken from CPP standard draft N4713.

---

From the quote it may not be clear how `Bar<void>`'s constructor can appear in `Foo`'s constructor as `Foo`'s constructor is `constexpr`. But as noted in the comments, `constexpr` is not the same as constant expression. `Foo`'s constructor is is not an expression, much less a constant expression.

Comment: Allows it to compile, yet the template is ill-formed NDR. Interesting.

Comment: "even though a call to such a function cannot appear in a constant expression". Doesn't this mean that `Bar<void>`'s constructor cannot appear in `Foo`'s constructor (`Foo`'s constructor is constexpr, and `Bar<void>`'s isn't, so it cannot appear)?

Comment: @geza - The constructor is constexpr but not a constant expression (it's not an expression at all).

Comment: @geza: Agree with StoryTeller's interpretation. Constructor is not an expression.

Comment: @StoryTeller: okay, thanks, reading this quote several time + your comment, now I understand what's going on. But, now I fail to understand the logic behind this: "fail to satisfy the requirements for a ... constexpr constructor, that specialization is still a ... constexpr constructor". What? Why?

Comment: @geza - Honestly, I'm not sure why it's worded like that instead of silently removing the constexpr property.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation about my other question? How to detect whether `Foo` will be initialized statically? If not, maybe I remove that part of my question, and ask a new question.

Comment: @geza: I think answering the other question might involve using helper classes, traits. etc. So better remove that part from this question and ask a new question.

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632120/how-can-i-detect-that-a-constuctor-is-really-constexpr-so-i-can-utilize-static