# How can I detect that a constuctor is really constexpr, so I can utilize static initialization?

Tags: c++, c++17

Look at this code:

```
struct NonConstexpr {
    NonConstexpr() { }
};

template <typename T>
struct Bar {
    NonConstexpr nonConstexpr;

    constexpr Bar() { }
};

struct Foo {
    Bar<void> bar;

    constexpr Foo() { }
};
```

In this code, `Foo`'s constructor is tagged as `constexpr`, but it cannot appear in a constant expression, as it actually fails to satisfy the requirements of this. You can read the details of this in my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53630837/is-this-a-bug-constexpr-constructor-silently-becomes-non-constexpr).

My question is: can I detect somehow compile-time, that `Foo`'s constructor actually won't behave as `constexpr`?

The reason I ask this, I'd like to detect that a global variable of `Foo` will be statically initialized or not (I'd like to put a `static_assert` on this, as my global `Foo` object must be initialized statically).

Note, that the straightforward solution, to temporarily add `constexpr` to the variable doesn't work, as my `Foo` has a non-trivial destructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Clang, use `[[clang::require_constant_initialization]]` on the variable. Otherwise, I don't know of a way.

The committee is looking at standardizing this as a keyword.

Comment: Thanks very much, this is exactly what I need! It doesn't matter too much that only clang supports this, as one compiler is enough which checks this.

Answer (score 1):

The only (current, toolchain-independent) way to prevent the compiler dropping the constexpr silently that I'm aware of, is to assign to a constexpr:

```
struct NonConstexpr {
    NonConstexpr() { }
};

template <typename T>
struct Bar {
    NonConstexpr nonConstexpr;

    constexpr Bar() { }
};

struct Foo {
    Bar<void> bar;

    constexpr Foo() { }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr auto f = Foo();
    return 0;
}
```

... will fail to compile with `constexpr constructor calls non-constexpr function "Bar<T>::Bar() [with T=void]"`

Comment: @Madhusudhan What does that look like?

Comment: @Madhusudhan Please show how you would expect this `static_assert` to look.

Comment: @geza: What does the triviality of the constructor have to do with it? He's using the default constructor you declared, which you marked `constexpr`. What part of that won't work?

Comment: @NicolBolas: sorry, I meant destructor.

Comment: `Foo` has a non-trivial destructor, so this solution doesn't work unfortunately, because it will always fail, even if the type has a proper constexpr constructor.

Comment: @geza: If the type is not a literal type... what's the point of giving it a `constexpr` constructor? `constexpr` is *not* the same thing as "do this at compile-time". You can only enforce compile-time execution if you use the object in a place that *requires* compile-time execution, like initializing a `constexpr` variable.

Comment: @NicolBolas: To make sure that a global variable gets statically initialized instead of dynamically. The standard guarantees this for (real) constexpr constructors, doesn't it (I'm not 100% sure, but this should be true, as I interpret the standard)?

Comment: What is keeping you from making the global variable `constexpr`?

Comment: @geza: "*The standard guarantees this for (real) constexpr constructors, doesn't it*" No, it does not. It guarantees only that things which *have to be* executed at compile time will be executed at compile-time. A constructor that happens to be declared `constexpr` used to initialize a non-`constexpr` variables does not *have* to be executed at compile time in order for the code to work. Therefore, it's dealer's choice.

Comment: @MaxLanghof: The fact that the destructor is non-trivial, and therefore the type is not a literal type.

Comment: @NicolBolas: hmm. The doesn't the standard guarantee that the variable will be constant initialized, if it has a proper `constexpr` constructor? This would make my whole question invalid/unnecessary.