# Constexpr constructor fails to satisfy the requirements, but still constexpr. Why?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

The standard says about template constexpr functions/constructors in [dcl.constexpr/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#6):

> If the instantiated template specialization of a constexpr function template or member function of a class template would fail to satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr constructor, that specialization is still a constexpr function or constexpr constructor, even though a call to such a function cannot appear in a constant expression. If no specialization of the template would satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function or constexpr constructor when considered as a non-template function or constructor, the template is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

The interesting part is:

> fail to satisfy the requirements for a ... constexpr constructor, that specialization is still a ... constexpr constructor

So, even if a constructor is marked with `constexpr`, it may not be used in a constant expression.

Why does this rule exist? Why isn't `constexpr` removed, when a function doesn't satisfy the requirements?

The current behavior is bad in two ways:

- the non-constexpr-ness isn't caught at the closest possible location, but at the actual constexpr expression, where it is used. So we have to find the offending part, where `constexpr` silently removed.
- an object, which is intended to be statically initialized (because it has a `constexpr` constructor), will be [dynamically initialized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632120/how-can-i-detect-that-a-constuctor-is-really-constexpr-so-i-can-utilize-static) without any errors/warnings (because the constructor isn't "really" constexpr).

Does this rule have some pros, which balances the cons of it?

Comment: Interestingly, if you go back to read earlier proposals on this - e.g. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2235.pdf - you find that the wording is as you suggest it should be.

Comment: @JackAidley: woa, good find! I'll trace, maybe there are some discussion about this somewhere (for others, it is on page 13, bullet point 5).

Comment: The change in wording seems to arise from the fix to this defect report, but I can't figure out why: http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1358 - perhaps someone else can?

Comment: Hm, isn't the "Additional note (January, 2013):" exactly the topic of this question? So it seems the committee is aware?

Comment: Side note: there is now [consteval](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) that behaves this way.

Answer (score 5):

This rule allows you to write a templated constructor/function and mark it as `constexpr` even when it's not always `constexpr` (only at least sometimes).

For example, `std::pair` has [`constexpr` constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair), but it is of course usable outside of constant expressions.

This is quite sensible, because otherwise you would have to duplicate all these functions (once with `constexpr` and once without), even if the code is exactly the same. Let's not even consider ambiguity.

Since it is generally impossible to prove that a template cannot ever satisfy `constexpr`, no diagnostic is required for it (but it's ill-formed so compilers can complain to you if they can prove this for a given case).

You are correct that this is not very useful if you want to specify "this function shall *only* be usable in constant expression", but that's not what this wording is aiming for.

Edit: To clarify, `constexpr` **for functions** only means *"legal to evaluate inside a constant expression"* (more precise wording [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)), **not** *"can only be evaluated at compile-time"*. By contrast, `constexpr` variables must be initialized with a constant expression.

---

Another edit: We have exact wording to discuss, thanks to @JackAidley!

> If the instantiated template specialization of a constexpr function template would fail to satisfy the requirements for a constexpr function,
>   the `constexpr` specifier is ignored and the specialization is not a constexpr function.

The problem with this is that "there is at least one set of arguments for which the function can be constant-evaluated" is part of the "requirements for a constexpr function". Therefore, compilers cannot implement this clause, since it is not possible to prove (in general) whether such a set exists for a given function (or a function template instantiation). You either have to muddy this requirement further or give up on this aspect. It seems the committee chose the latter.

Comment: There is no problem with marking a constructor of a template class with `constexpr`. The problem is, when this template is specialized, and the compiler knows that the constructor is not `constexpr`, then it shouldn't treat it as `constexpr`. But because of this rule, it still treat it as `constexpr`. And the failure will come late, when the constructor is actually used in a constant expression. But it could come sooner, when the "fake" `constexpr` constructor used in another `constexpr` constructor (if the `consexpr`-ness would be semantially removed).

Comment: Or the failure doesn't come at all, when the constructor isn't used in a constant expression, so wrong code will be compiled (in the case of dynamic initialization instead of static).

Comment: I think you misunderstand what `constexpr` means for functions. `constexpr` functions _can_ be evaluated at compile time (for some set of arguments). They are not _guaranteed_ to be for every choice of arguments. If you require a value to be initialized at compile-time, mark the value as `constexpr` (this will force the issue). Marking only the function just makes it legal to use the function in a constant expression, it doesn't require every invocation to be at compile-time.

Comment: Sure, but current compilers give error (even it is NDR), when the case is trivial, and an expression never gives a constexpr. But because of this rule (supposedly), they don't do this.

Comment: @geza Please show such a case. Note that functions marked `constexpr` violating the bullet points listed [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr) must be diagnosed. A compiler _can_ (but is _not required_) to additionally diagnose cases where no set of arguments could lead to compile-time evaluation ("No diagnostic is required for a violation of this bullet."). Note that the keyword is used to make the compiler help you, not to make the compiler do something it otherwise would not.

Comment: Look at the code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632120/how-can-i-detect-that-a-constuctor-is-really-constexpr-so-i-can-utilize-static. Put a `NonConstexpr` member into `Foo`. Then it won't compile anymore (checked with gcc and clang).

Comment: Check out the comments under the question: Jack Aidley found an older proposal, where it worked just like it would be logical (for me). But perhaps that proposal was very much different in other ways too. But anyways, they have changed this because of something.

Comment: I meant an example for the "current compiler gives error when the case is trivial". What you linked is just a demonstration of everything said so far, and I'm running out of ways to phrase it. Regarding "why did they change it from the proposal", see the beginning of my answer for an educated guess. Or rather, let me ask you: If `constexpr` worked as you (and the original proposal) wanted it to, how many `std::pair` constructors would there have to be? How many of them would share identical code?

Comment: That is an example of that. If you add a `NonConstexpr` member into `Foo`, it won't compile. Trivial example, `Foo` isn't put into a constant expression, yet it fails to compile, as `Foo`'s constructor never can be part of a constant expression.

Comment: No change would be needed for `std::pair` at all.

Comment: @geza: Then it's not clear what you're even suggesting. If applying `constexpr` to a template class constructor which gets instantiated with a type where being `constexpr` is not possible results in a compile error, how do you make such a type conditionally `constexpr` without duplicating constructors and using SFINAE gymnastics?

Comment: @NicolBolas: Hmm, maybe I don't see something trivial here. `constexpr` is written for the constructor of the template (just like now). But, if the specialization would result in a non-constexpr constructor, then the `constexpr` would be ignored. Just like if it wasn't written there. Just like this old proposal says. Do I overlook something here, which makes this non-viable?

Comment: @geza: If that's what you're asking for, how is that functionally different from what we have at present?

Comment: @NicolBolas: It would mean that my current example would fail to compile, as current compilers diagnose trivial cases.

Comment: @geza: If "my current example" refers to the question you linked to, that *already* fails to compile. If that's not the case, then what is your current example?

Comment: @NicolBolas: hmm, which compiler? For me, compiles. Both with gcc and clang.

Comment: @NicolBolas: gcc, clang, msvc compiles it, icc rejects: https://godbolt.org/z/ggGfya

Answer (score 4):

In [earlier versions](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2235.pdf) of the suggestion for the change to the language, it operated as you suggest:

> If the instantiated template specialization of a constexpr function
>   template would fail to satisfy the requirements for a constexpr
>   function,the `constexpr`specifier is ignored and the specialization is
>   not a constexpr function.

But it was later changed. I was unable to track down any definitive answer to your question but I think that it is reasonable to believe that the answer is that `constexpr` make other semantic changes to the code and these are retained even though the function is no longer usable in other `constexpr` statements. If you look at [defect report 1358](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1358) which includes the change to the current wording, you can see an intermediate form of words that includes the a note about retaining `const` status regardless.

I also think that while the retention of `constexpr` status is unintuitive, both of your arguments against it are wrong:

1. Catching the `constexpr` when the template instantiation is made goes against how C++ templates usually work - you only get an error when you try and use the template in a way it cannot be used for that type; merely not being able to complete the entire signature is not an error. To introduce special case mechanics for `constexpr` would be unnecessarily confusing and limit usefulness since you'd now need to write different templates for `constexpr`able and un-`constexpr`able types.
2. *Because* it maintains the `constexpr` specifier the fallback isn't to general runtime dynamic initialisation but to dynamic initialisation at the time at which `static`s are initialised. Which may cause problems because of the Static Initialisation Order Fiasco but does at least happen before the `main()` function is entered.

Comment: @T.C. I can't help but feel whoever decided that the initialisation of `static`s is not static initialisation and that the Static Initialisation Order Fiasco occurs only with dynamic initialisation and not static initialisation was having a little giggle to themselves at the time.